# Nodejs Bluebird Promise.map for large collections not working

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a large collection having 20000+ promises and I want to resolve it using Bluebird's Promise.map. However my code does not execute successfully but times out after about 15-20 mins.

Error I get is the timeout error.

When the collection has less than 2000 promises, the code executes in less than 10 seconds successfully.

Please help me in finding either an alternative to Promise.map or any other way so that the code does not timeout.

```
service.getSomePromises().then(function(arrSomePromises){
    var promises = []; 
    for (var i = 0;i < arrSomePromises.length; i++){
        var getDetailsObject = _getDetails(_db, i);
        promises.push(getDetailsObject);
    }

    //Below is the code that times out
    return Promise.map(promises, function(doc){
        return reportData.push(doc);
    })
}
```

Comment: You may be attempting too many concurrent connections which may be either exhausting local resources or overwhelming the target.  I'd suggest using the `concurrency` option with `Promise.map()`.   Start with setting it to something small like 10 and if that works, then experiment with raising it.

Comment: Also, now that you've added code, this is the wrong way to use `Promise.map()`.  Normally, you pass it an array of data and a function that carries out some async operation on that data and returns a promise.  You don't pass it an array of promises.  One would use  `Promise.all()` with an array of promises.

Comment: The code you show doesn't make any sense because `promise.length` is `0` so your `for` loop won't do anything.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong code. This is an abstract of a larger code that I had written and was trying to modify it. I have fixed it now. I hear you on using the concurrency option. I completely missed. Let me try it and post back the results in a while. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a timeout error, then you are probably just overwhelming that target server with too many simultaneous requests to the some host.  For large numbers of request, you will want to limit how many simultaneous requests are in flight to the same host at the same time.  I would suggest starting with a limit of about 5-10 at a time and you can then experiment with raising it to see if that actually improves your performance or not.  Target servers have a limit to how many simultaneous requests that can be productive serving all at once.  Going higher than that just burdens the infrastructure and eventually just causes timeout errors.

Bluebird's `Promise.map()` when used properly (which you are not doing) has a `concurrency` option that will tell it the max number of concurrent connections you want it to use at once.  But, to make use of that option, you have to use `Bluebird.map()` properly where you pass it an array of data (not an array of promises that you've already started the async operations for) and a function that returns a promise that operates on one of those data items.

Here's an example of how you would use `Promise.map()` correctly with the `concurrency` option.

```
let someLargeArrayOfData = [...];
Promise.map(someLargeArrayOfData, function(item) {
    return request(item);     // async function that returns promise
}, {concurrency: 10}).then(function(results) {
    // results is an array of data from all the resolved promises
}).catch(function(err) {
    // process error here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try to update the code to work on the array of data and not the promises. However, if I have an array of promises, is there a way to work with them, other than promises.all ?

Comment: @user2434285 - An array of promises usually represents a set of async operations that have already been started. At that point, there's nothing more to know except when they're done which is what `Promise.all()` does.  You need a solution that doesn't start too many async operations at once.